# Can't apply other const within a forEach function

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript.

So far my code only changes the color of the text of the button, I am trying to make it where  enabling the button also reveals the hidden paragraph.
Always says that the arrow and answers are undefined

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
const answers = document.querySelectorAll('p');
const arrows = document.querySelectorAll('arrow');
console.log(buttons);
console.log(answers);
console.log(arrows);


buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', function(){
        button.style.color = 'red';
        answers.style.display = 'block';
    });
})
```

Alternate code i did was

```
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const answers = document.querySelector('.answer');
const arrow = document.querySelector('.arrow');


button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    answers.style.display = 'block';
    arrow.style.transform = 'rotate(180deg)'

});
```

This one worked. However, I would have to label every element in my HTML that needs to change.

Here is sample HTML:

```html
<div class="faq">
          <button>How many team members can I invite? <img class="arrow" src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg"></button>
          <p class="answer">You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on
          team members for the Premium plan.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="faq">
          <button>What is the maximum file upload size?<img class="arrow"src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg"> </button>
          <p class="answer"> No more than 2GB. All files in your account must fit your allotted storage space.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="faq">
          <button>How do I reset my password?<img class="arrow" src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg"></button>
          <p class="answer">Click “Forgot password” from the login page or “Change password” from your profile page.
            A reset link will be emailed to you.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="faq">
            <button>Can I cancel my subscription?<img class="arrow" src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg"></button>
          <p class="answer">Yes! Send us a message and we’ll process your request no questions asked.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="faq">
           <button>Do you provide additional support?<img class="arrow" src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg"></button>
          <p class="answer">Chat and email support is available 24/7. Phone lines are open during normal business hours.</p>
```

Comment: you cannot do this `answers.style.display = 'block';`  its an element collection. You need iterarate like you do for the buttons.

Comment: `answers[0].style.display = 'block';`

Comment: you would better iterate through the elements with the faq class, and then use querySelector on the faq to get the respective button and answer.

Comment: You should also have a look at the [DOMContentLoaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event). Your query selector to get all the *arrows* will also not work, as it is a class, so you must use `.arrows` instead of `arrows`

Comment: I this meant to be an "accordion" where you click on one button and it displays the content, and all the other open panels close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should grab the clicked element from inside the click event handler using `window.event.target`. Your problem was trying to access from your click handler to variables defined outside of its scope and having a different meaning. Everytime the click handler gets invoked it needs a strategy to fetch the clicked element and all the elements bound to its context to which you wish to change the style.

But there's a chance I didn't correctly get what you were really asking... in that case I hope to hear a feedback.

I made a demo here to show how:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

function resetButtonStyles(){
  document.querySelectorAll('div.parent.active').forEach( divactive =>{
    divactive.classList.remove('active');
  });
}

buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    
      document.querySelector('div.parent.active')
        ?.classList.remove('active');

      const clickedButton = window.event.currentTarget;
      const parentDiv = clickedButton.closest('div.parent');
      const boundAnswer = parentDiv.querySelector('p');

      parentDiv.classList.add("active");

      //clickedButton.style.color = 'red';
      //boundAnswer.style.border = 'solid red 2px';
    });
})
```

```css
.active p{
  color: red;
}

.active button{
  border: solid red 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>Answers 1</p>
  <button>Button 1</button>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <p>Answers 2</p>
  <button>Button 2</button>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <p>Answers 2</p>
  <button>Button 2</button>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <p>Answers 2</p>
  <button>Button 2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you this worked, however I have a question.    How do I make it where pressing another button makes the other displayed blocked element disappear?

Comment: I changed my answer so that instead of changing the style of individual elements, it just adds the css class `active` to the div parent element of the clicked button. So that to reset the style of the previously clicked button, it just removes the class active from the div having it when the handler gets fired

Answer (score 0):

It sound like you're after an accordion effect.

1. Wrap your markup in a container so you can use [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/).
2. Cache the container, and the answer elements.
3. When you click on a button hide all the answers, switch the arrow, and then show that button's answer.

[Note: [I've used unicode in CSS](https://unicode-table.com/en/1F782/) to show the arrows instead of images].

```js
// Cache the elements
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const answers = document.querySelectorAll('.answer');
const arrows = document.querySelectorAll('.arrow');

// Add a listener to the container
container.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick(e) {

  // If we click a button
  if (e.target.matches('button')) {

    // Remove all the answers
    answers.forEach(answer => answer.classList.remove('show'));

    // Update the arrows
    arrows.forEach(arrow => {
      arrow.classList.remove('down');
      arrow.classList.add('right');
    });
    
    // Get the parent of the clicked element
    const parent = e.target.closest('.faq');

    // Change the arrow...
    const arrow = e.target.querySelector('.arrow');
    arrow.classList.remove('right');
    arrow.classList.add('down');
    
    // ...and then show the answer
    const answer = parent.querySelector('.answer');
    answer.classList.add('show');

  }

}
```

```css
.answer { display: none; }
.show { display: block; }
.down:after { content: '\1F783'; }
.right:after { content: '\1F782'; }
button:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="faq">
    <button>How many team members can I invite?
      <span class="arrow right"></span>
    </button>
    <p class="answer">You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on team members for the Premium plan.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="faq">
    <button>What is the maximum file upload size?
      <span class="arrow right"></span>
    </button>
    <p class="answer"> No more than 2GB. All files in your account must fit your allotted storage space.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="faq">
    <button>How do I reset my password?
      <span class="arrow right"></span>
    </button>
    <p class="answer">Click “Forgot password” from the login page or “Change password” from your profile page. A reset link will be emailed to you.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="faq">
    <button>Can I cancel my subscription?
      <span class="arrow right"></span>
    </button>
    <p class="answer">Yes! Send us a message and we’ll process your request no questions asked.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
const buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
const answers = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
const arrows = document.getElementsByTagName('arrow');
console.log(buttons);
console.log(answers);
console.log(arrows);


for (var j = 0; j < buttons.length; j++){
       var button = buttons[j];
       button.addEventListener('click', function(){
           button.style.color = 'red';
           for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++){
             answers[i].style.display = 'block'
           }        
    });
}
```

Comment: An unformatted code-dump without notes or explanatory documentation. Not a great answer.

Comment: Au contraire mon ami, 'tis a goodly response.